# 3 pin 801s sensor

Tags: rpi.gpio

I plan to use the following guide with a Pi 1 B+ and 2 801s vibration sensors.

https://github.com/Shmoopty/rpi-appliance-monitor/blob/master/README.md

However, their example uses a 4 pin 801s whilst the one that I've found (https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00NNDBMTY/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A1NBUX8FDB1DWX) is a 3 pin model.

Does anyone know if this is a problem and, also, which pins I should connect both of the sensors to?  To clarify, they will both be connected to the same Pi.

Lastly, being a complete noob (as my son would say), does anyone have any good tips or guides when it comes to soldering the connections to the Pi?  I've played around with Pis but never added sensors before.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Steve

Comment: *"does anyone have any good tips or guides when it comes to soldering the connections to the Pi"* -> Yeah don't.  *"...a 3 pin model"* -> Quick glance implies to me that means it is probably analog only, and the Pi doesn't have analog inputs.  However, the input may still change state (high to low).  But don't power it from 5V.  If it requires 5V, you cannot attach it directly to the pi period.

Comment: The module you've linked to states working voltage of 3-5V so you're fine to connect it directly as long as you power it from the Pi's 3.3V pin.

Answer (score 1):

That's my project you link to.

The 801s you found has a digital pin, and that's the important one.  An 801s module may also have an analog pin, but that's not used in this project.  Reading analog signals to a Raspberry Pi is a bit trickier.

Good luck!